# How to determine if $ \int_0^1 \frac{(\ln x)^5}{\sqrt{ x}}\mathrm dx$ diverges or converges without calculating the integral itself

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm new here and I hope I follow the rules of asking a question correctly.

This integral $$ \int_0^1 \frac{(\ln x)^5}{\sqrt x} \mathrm dx$$ is giving me a hard time proving divergence or convergence.

Can you guys help me? 
Thanks in advance! <3

Comment: Why are you adding `\mathstrut` to $x$?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Do you mean me? I tried editing and used `\!`, my usual technique until now, but you showed me a better way :)

Comment: Try integration by parts and see what happens

Comment: @The "...without calculating the integral itself..."

Comment: @SK19 I was saying to OP. Btw, you can learn more good ways of formatting Math [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Jaideep Khare when I've created this topic it didnt show me the sqrt sign, onñy the letters "sqrt", so i looked online how to write the sign itself and found it...

Comment: $-\frac{1}{2}>-1$, hence the function $g(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{1}x^\alpha\,dx $ is a $C^{\infty}$ function in a neighbourhood of $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}$.<br>
By differentiation under the integral sign, the claim follows by just considering $g^{(V)}(\alpha)$ at $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}$.<br>
This approach also gives the exact value of the given integral in a very straightforward way: $g(\alpha)$ is just $\frac{1}{\alpha+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Make the substitution $y=-\ln x$. Then the integral equals
$$-\int_0^\infty y^5e^{-y/2}\,dy$$
whose convergence/divergence seems much more obvious...

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Im not sure if i can touch the integral at all, I thought of proving it through the integral/p/comparison tests..

Answer (score 1):

Consider the integrand $-\dfrac{(\ln x)^{5}}{\sqrt{x}}=\dfrac{(\ln x^{-1})^{5}}{\sqrt{x}}$, we know that for large $u>0$, $\ln u<u^{1/20}$, so for small $x>0$, we have $(\ln x^{-1})^{5}<x^{-1/4}$, then $\dfrac{(\ln x^{-1})^{5}}{\sqrt{x}}<\dfrac{1}{x^{3/4}}$ and we know that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\eta}\dfrac{1}{x^{3/4}}dx<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Why did you put a minus infront of (lnx)^5?

Comment: That is then a nonnegative integrand, and it is enough to look up an integrable upper bound function, which is in this case that $\dfrac{1}{x^{3/4}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is use limit comparison test with

$$\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1+\frac12}{2}}}=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$

Indeed $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^\frac34} \mathrm dx$ converges and
since $\forall a>0$ and n we have that

$$x^a\log^n x \to 0$$

in this case we have

$$\frac{\frac{(\ln x)^5}{\sqrt x}}{\frac1{x^\frac34}}=x^\frac14\ln^5x\to0$$

and thus $\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln x)^5}{\sqrt x} \mathrm dx$ concerges too.